# Magento 2.3.1 Frontend stock not correct after sql update

Tags: magento2, database, php-7

I'm updating stock via SQL update along the lines of  below website https://www.danjoseph.me/2017/01/12/magento-2-database-level-inventory-management/

The price and qty is updated and visible in backend but the frontend still seems to reflect the 'old' qty & pric. I have reindexed & flushed cache but backorder message remains. The cataloginventory_stock_item and cataloginventory_stock_status tables all look correct are there any other tables that could cause this??

As soon as I manually save the product in the admin backend (without altering any values) the stock is reflected correctly

Comment: It should probably be caused by your external cache processor (for example: Varnish). Did you try refreshing your cache created by external processor? If you use Varnish you can just restart the Varnish service by executing `sudo service varnish restart`.

Comment: I'm not using varnish..

Comment: Found out that caused by inventory_source_item table that also needs updating. Not sure of the implications of this now in regards to indexing & grouped products. As grouped products now have an SKU although it's basically fictional I'm presuming that this table needs to be updated with their status and availability as well as the standard simple products